# Integration test best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

I looked in stackoverflow and could fine [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328730/integration-testing-best-practices) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433627/integration-test-best-practice) questions that have a similar title than this one, but none of it answers what I'm asking. Sorry if this is duplicated.

In unity tests, there is a guideline that says "[One assertion per test](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/06/testing-one-assertion-per-test.html)". By reading around stackoverflow and the internet, it is commonly accepted that this rule can be relaxed a bit, but every unit test should test one aspect of the code, or one behavior. This works well because when a test fails you can immediately see what failed and fixing it most likely the test will not fail again in other point in the future.

This works well for Rails unit tests, and I have been using it for functional testing as well without any problem. But when it comes to integration tests, it is somewhat implicit that you should have many assertions in your tests. Apart from that, they usually repeat tests that are already done once in functional and in unit tests.

So, what are considered good practices when writing integration tests in these two factors:

1. **Length of the integration tests**: How to measure when a integration test should be splited in two? Number of requests? Or larger is always better
2. **Number of assertions on integration tests**: Should it repeat the assertions presented on unit tests and functional tests about the current state of the system every time, or should it have only 5 or so asserts on the end to test if the correct output was generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully someone will provide a more authoritative answer, but my understanding is that an integration test should be built around a specific feature. For example, in an online store, you might write one integration test to make sure that it's possible to add items to your cart, and another integration test to make sure it's possible to check out.

> How long should an integration test be?

As long as it takes to cover a feature, and no more. Some features are small, some are large, and their size is a matter of taste. When they're too big, they can easily be decomposed into several logical sub-features. When they're too small, their integration tests will look like view or controller tests.

> > How many assertions should they have?

As few as possible, while still being useful. This is true of all tests, but it goes doubly for integration tests because they're so slow. This means testing only the things that are most important, and trying not to test things that are implied by other data. In the case of the checkout feature, I might assert that the order was created for the right person and has the right total, but leave the exact items untested (since my architecture might generate the total from the items). I wouldn't make any assertions before that that I didn't have to, since traversing the application—filling this field, clicking that button, waiting for this modal to open—covers all the integration behavior I need tested, and anything else could be covered by view tests if they need to be tested at all.

All together, in general this means that whereas unit tests tend to be only a couple lines long and preceded by a larger setup block, Rails integration tests tend to be a dozen lines long or more (most of which are interaction), and lack a setup block entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 for being brave and be the first one after weeks.

Answer (score 2):

**Length of the integration tests:** I agree that length here doesn't matter that much. It's more about the feature you're testing and how many steps does it take to test it. For example let's say you're testing a wizard of five steps which creates a project. I would put all the five steps in one test end check if the relevant data appeared on screen. However I would split the test if the wizard would allow for different scenarios that need to be covered.

**Number of assertions on integration tests:** Don't test things that are already tested in other test, but **make sure user expectations are met.** So test what, the user expects to see on the screen not back-end specific code. Sometimes you might still need to check the right data is in the database, for example when its not supposed to appear on the screen.